# How to install aws s3api on mac

Tags: amazon-web-services

We wish to access the `s3api` that is described in *Amazon* docs here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3api-commands.html

An example of a feature we would use:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket MyBucket --grant-full-control 'emailaddress="user1@example.com",emailaddress="user2@example.com"'
--grant-read 'uri="http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"'
```

The associated setup pages only setup the  `aws cli` or `aws s3`  but not `aws s3api`.  So how to download /install the `s3api`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) - if you don't already have it, you'll *definitely* want it if you're doing any kind of serious dev work on a Mac - to install (or update) the AWS CLI. First, make sure the `brew` command is available, and if not, install it following the instructions from the link above. Next, remove any currently-installed AWS CLI from your `PATH`, unless it was also installed from Homebrew. Finally, open a terminal and enter these commands:

```
brew update
brew install awscli
aws s3api help
```

You should see the help documentation for `s3api` (you can hit `q` to get back to the command line). Before you can actually use it, you'll need to configure the AWS CLI; the easy way to do that is with this command:

```
aws configure
```

(If you already had an AWS CLI configured, you can skip that step; it should find your old config file no problem.) After you configure your keys and such, you should be good to go with commands like the one in your question.